# How to use Glue to map struct column to jsonb column in RDS postgres

Tags: json, amazon-rds, aws-glue

1. The original json file in S3. For example :Table "customer_s3", {"id":1, "name":"Bob","address":{"state":"TX", "city":"Austin"}}
2. I use Glue crawler to create a catalog table "customer_from_s3" from json file in S3, in this catalog table the data type of one column("address") is struct.
3. I use Glue to create a connection to RDS Postgres, and create a crawler to get the schema of the table "customer_rds" from RDS Postegres database. the schema : "id":int, "name":string, "address":jsonb.
4. Then I want to use Glue ETLJobs to read the data from "customer_s3" json file in S3 , transform(here I do nothing), then save the data into "customer_rds" table in RDS Postgres,

The question: I can not map the "address" column (type: struct)(from "customer_from_s3" catalog table in glue) to the RDS Postgress as a column "address" (jsonb) using Glue ETLJobs.

Is there any solution?

I try to use Glue Visual ETL jobs to create an ETL Job to do the work, but it failed because of the `WriteDynamicFrame. Can't get JDBC type for struct`

Example
The original data:

`{"id":1, "name":"Bob","address":{"state":"TX", "city":"Austin"}}`

The final table look like as below:

```
+--+-----+---------------------------------+ 
|id|name |address                          | 
+--+-----+---------------------------------+ 
|1 |"Bob"| {"state":"TX", "city":"Austin"} | 
+--+-----+---------------------------------+
```

So I hope everything for address column just keep the same when I store to the database, but the data type is jsonb.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried is set the data type of `address` column to string in glue and in RDS database, in the database, run another procedure to transform string type to jsonb for `address` column.

But I have to say , it is not a good idea. It add more time to execute in database, and I still don't know how to convert struct type to jsonb in database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).